# OnActivityResult never called inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to implement the call activity with result method.
Thus, here is the calling instructions (they are inside a fragment):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarFilterActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(CalendarFilterActivity.KEY_EVENTS, mEvent);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

KEY_EVENTS is just a String.
The CalendarFilterActivity executes these instructions:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(KEY_RESULT, result);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Now, the fragment is showed but the overrided onActivityResult method in the fragment is never executed.
It happen sometimes that, calling the activity, mEvent is null. But I don't think this would be the problem.
Anyone knows why please?

Comment: Where does `CalendarFilterActivity` go through the chunk of code you mention?

Comment: Are you ovverriding `onActivityResult` also inside the Activity which contains the Fragment? In that case, are you calling the `super` properly?

Comment: @rciovati yes but for other purposes (other results from other activities). How can I forward the result to the OnActivityResult of the fragment then?

Comment: You don't need to manually forward the result. Just call `super.onActivityResult(...);`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. In the Activity that hosts the fragment I've overrided onActivityResult and the first code line is `super.onActivityResult(...);` but the method `onActivityResult(...);` in the fragment is never called. Where should I put the `super.onActivityReslut(...);` you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The reason was that my activity was tagged with a `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest.